# IE10/Telerik compatibility problems

Tags: telerik, width, compatibility, internet-explorer-10, radgrid

I'm developing a C#/Dot Net 4.0 Web app in VS2012 using the latest Telerik controls, particularly the RadGrid.  My machine is Windows 7.

Everything is working fine in Firefox and Chrome.  IE10 is a different story.

If I run the app off my local instance of IIS Express, it works fine, not even needing compatibility mode.  If I run the published version of the app off our web server the grid will not behave normally in 'normal' mode.  Popup links will not work and the page size settings cannot be changed.

If I run it in Compatibility mode, the grid more or less works but it shrinks to half the width of the window and nothing seems to fix it.

Frankly I don't know where to begin troubleshooting this.  Suggestions?

Comment: What doctype are you using on your pages?

Comment: I'm going to say this problem is solved.  What I did is fix the widths in the RadGrid prerender.   foreach (GridColumn col in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.RenderColumns)
                {  if (col.UniqueName == "Something")
                        col.HeaderStyle.Width = Unit.Percentage(10.0);  etc....